# Doctrine DQL - sum of orders by brand and by date in one query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm working with Symfony 2.

I need to create a DQL query that would provide me with data to be displayed in the this form:

[image]

I need the sum of all orders by brand and by year.

The required tables in the database look like this:

Brand:

[image]

VOrder:

[image]

So far, I have managed to extract a year, order value and a brand for every orderthe following DQL, but this is nowhere close where I want to be:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT SUBSTRING(o.date, 1, 4), o.value, b.name
         FROM AppBundle:VOrder o
         LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Brand b WITH b.id = b
         GROUP BY o.date"
    );
```

My question boils down to these:
1. Is it possible to achieve the desired result (see the table above) with only one query?
2. Where do I go from here to get the needed data?

Comment: Maybe an idea to do `SELECT YEAR(o.date), o.value ...` instead of a substring?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single query, but I think it's best to do this without DQL.

[The documentation explains the drawbacks of using DQL for aggregate fields](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html?highlight=sum)

Have a look at [how to run native SQL with doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) in the docs.

The query itself should do a `GROUP BY YEAR(date)`, and a `SUM(value)`:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(o.date), 
  SUM(o.value), 
  b.name 
FROM brands b 
LEFT JOIN orders o 
  ON o.brand_id = b.id 
GROUP BY YEAR(o.date);
```

Comment: YEAR() does not seem to be a function Doctrine recognizes.

Comment: It's not DQL, it's plain sql, you should run it as native sql as described in the answer. are you running mysql or sqlite or something else?

Comment: I'm running MySql. You're right it's probably easier to go without DQL - an upvote is due. I managed, however, to find DQL I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need next query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT YEAR(o.date), sum(o.value), b.name
     FROM AppBundle:VOrder o
     LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Brand b WITH b.id = o.brand_id
     GROUP BY YEAR(o.date), b.name"
);
```

Comment: where does this query sum the results of a specific year?

Comment: @Michael, this is actually close to what was needed. It looks, however, that the query is SQL and DQL mixed together. Apart from that, I believe that there was a mistake in `WITH b.id = b` that I made initially. Still, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

With help from my colleague, I managed to find DQL that does exactly what I was looking for:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT SUBSTRING(o.date, 1, 4) AS year, SUM(o.value), b.name
         FROM AppBundle:Brand b
         LEFT JOIN AppBundle:VOrder o WITH o.brand = b.id
         GROUP BY year, b.id" 
    );
```

There is no YEAR() function on DQL, so the workaround was to use SUBSTRING().